# Change color of data url embedded SVG image

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG background image embedded in a CSS file as a data url:

```
.what { background: url('data: image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg> ... </svg') }
```

I want another element to have the same background image, only in a different color, but I don't want to repeat the whole SVG code.

```
<div class="what one">...</div>
<div class="what two">...</div>
```

#### So how do I change the color of a background SVG image?

No Javascript, please.

---

None of the other related questions answered this, because the solutions given there rely on serving two different files, which I want to avoid because I want to minimize file size for mobile users.

Comment: There are many "Related Answers" as you can see on the right hand side of this page but basically, it's **not possible** with CSS.

Comment: I think you would have to repeat the svg but with the different background color

Comment: You seem to have ruled out all possible answers i.e. two images or javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, as [Noah Blon explains](http://noahblon.com/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images/), it is possible to style the color of an SVG background image using CSS filters.

An example he gives on his site is:

```
.icon-blue {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(220deg) saturate(5);
    filter: hue-rotate(220deg) saturate(5);
}
```

Please visit his site for more information and two other solutions that do not involve changing the color but SVG background sprites and creating an "inverted" SVG that covers the background and is transparent where the background color shines through to create a colored form.

Unfortunately, [IE does not support filters](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter).

Comment: It does don't work with IE. But as long as today IE far not so important, there can be created a fall-back for such custom situation with pngs instead. (Yes, that's some additional step, but I rather use that in my projects).

Comment: It should be noted this solution technically does not "style the color of an SVG". It's a blunt filter on the entire DOM element, whatever the content is (SVG or not).

Answer (score 2):

You can't restyle the contents of a background image with CSS. It doesn't matter if it's an external SVG, or one applied as a Data URI.

Answer (score -2):

Check out this webpage: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/
Part way down the page is a header called "Now you can control with CSS!"
They appear to be changing the color of the image inline with statements such as

```
.kiwi {
    fill: #94d31b; 
}
```

Comment: Judging from the downvotes, I would assume this does not work as you are intending. My apologies.

Comment: The solution you present is appropriate for inline SVG and not background images which is what the OP has.

Comment: Sadly this one didn't answer OP but it was still helpful extra info. Maybe better in a comment or something but regardless I gave an up to remove one of those downs. I appreciate the effort here to assist :)